# How to stop overlapping two div?

Tags: css, html, twitter-bootstrap

This is my total code. There are two div. When I scroll down the page, the 2nd div is overlapping with the 1st one, and it goes below to the 1st div. As you can see in the screenshot, the image and paragraph are over the 1st div.but i want the two div's separate to each other and the 2nd one to properly sit in it's own place. I stack in this portion. Please help me out...thanks in advance

```css
body {
  overflow-x: hidden;
}

#particle {
  background-color: blue;
  position: fixed;
  top: 0;
  right: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  left: 0;
  height: 550px;
}

#overlay {
  position: relative;
}

#inner-banner-image {
  padding-top: 12%;
  width: 80%;
  margin: auto;
}

#banner-content {
  position: relative;
  padding-top: 6%;
  padding-bottom: 6%;
  overflow: hidden;
  margin-bottom: 12%;
  background-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.7);
  max-width: 520px;
  margin-top: 5%;
}

#button {
  color: #fff;
  background-color: #c9302c;
  border-color: #ac2925;
  padding: 10px 16px;
  font-size: 15px;
  width: 155px;
  border-radius: 6px;
}

.about {
  background-color: #C57ED3;
  padding-top: 100px;
  color: #490D40;
  height: 510px;
  text-align: center;
}

p {
  padding: 50px 50px;
  text-align: center;
  justify-content: center;
}
```

```html
<html>

<head>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css">

  <!--jQuery library-->
  <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.12.4/jquery.min.js"></script>

  <!--Latest compiled and minified JavaScript-->
  <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>


  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="resume.css" type="text/css">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://use.fontawesome.com/releases/v5.4.1/css/all.css">

  <title>
    RESUME</title>
</head>

<body>
  <div id="particle"></div>
  <div id="overlay">
    <div id="inner-banner-image">
      <center>
        <div id="banner-content">
          <marquee bgcolor="#c9302c" behavior="alternate">
            <font color="white">WELCOME TO OUR WEBSITE</marquee>
          <h1>We sell lifestyle</h1>
          <p>Flat 40% OFF on premium brands </p>
          <div id="button">
            <a href="products.php">Shop Now</a>
          </div>
        </div>
      </center>
    </div>
  </div>
  <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/particles.js/2.0.0/particles.min.js"></script>
  <script src="p.js"></script>


  <div class="about">
    <div class="row">
      <div class="col-12 col-md-4">
        <img src="p.jpg" class="img-thumbnail">
      </div>
      <div class="col-12 col-md-8">
        <h3>Main Description</h3>
        <p>Roll on the floor purring your whiskers off intrigued by the shower burrow under covers, and play time, rub face on everything, intently sniff hand, or pelt around the house and up and down stairs chasing phantoms. Attack feet. Damn that dog shake
          treat bag under the bed drink water out of the faucet for lick butt love to play with owner's hair tie. Swat at dog give attitude.</p>

        <div class="m">
          <a class="btn" id="download" href="#">
            <i class="fas fa-download">Download Resume</i>
          </a>
        </div>
        <div class="middle">
          <a class="btn" id="b" href="#">
            <i class="fab fa-facebook-f"></i>
          </a>
          <a class="btn" id="c" href="#">
            <i class="fab fa-twitter"></i>
          </a>
          <a class="btn" id="d" href="#">
            <i class="fab fa-linkedin-in"></i>
          </a>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</body>

</html>
```

[image: 1st example of output][image: 2nd example of output]

Comment: thanks @isherwood for ur suggetion.I remember that. :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If I understood correctly, you want the background of each section to scroll along with the content? Here you go:

```css
body {
  overflow-x: hidden;
}

#particle {
  position: fixed;
  height: 100%;
  width: 100%;
}

#overlay {
  background-color: blue;
  top: 0;
  right: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  left: 0;
  height: 550px;
}


#inner-banner-image {
  padding-top: 70px;
  width: 80%;
  margin: auto;
}

#banner-content {
  padding-top: 6%;
  padding-bottom: 6%;
  overflow: hidden;
  margin-bottom: 12%;
  background-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.7);
  max-width: 520px;
  margin-top: 5%;
}

#button {
  color: #fff;
  background-color: #c9302c;
  border-color: #ac2925;
  padding: 10px 16px;
  font-size: 15px;
  width: 155px;
  border-radius: 6px;
}

.about {
  background-color: #C57ED3;
  padding-top: 100px;
  color: #490D40;
  height: 510px;
  text-align: center;
}

p {
  padding: 50px 50px;
  text-align: center;
  justify-content: center;
}
```

```html
<html>

<head>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css">

  <!--jQuery library-->
  <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.12.4/jquery.min.js"></script>

  <!--Latest compiled and minified JavaScript-->
  <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>


  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="resume.css" type="text/css">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://use.fontawesome.com/releases/v5.4.1/css/all.css">

  <title>
    RESUME</title>
</head>

<body>
  <div id="particle"></div>
  <div id="overlay">
    <div id="inner-banner-image">
      <center>
        <div id="banner-content">
          <marquee bgcolor="#c9302c" behavior="alternate">
            <font color="white">WELCOME TO OUR WEBSITE</marquee>
          <h1>We sell lifestyle</h1>
          <p>Flat 40% OFF on premium brands </p>
          <div id="button">
            <a href="products.php">Shop Now</a>
          </div>
        </div>
      </center>
    </div>
  </div>

  <div class="about">
    <div class="row">
      <div class="col-12 col-md-4">
        <img src="p.jpg" class="img-thumbnail">
      </div>
      <div class="col-12 col-md-8">
        <h3>Main Description</h3>
        <p>Roll on the floor purring your whiskers off intrigued by the shower burrow under covers, and play time, rub face on everything, intently sniff hand, or pelt around the house and up and down stairs chasing phantoms. Attack feet. Damn that dog shake
          treat bag under the bed drink water out of the faucet for lick butt love to play with owner's hair tie. Swat at dog give attitude.</p>

        <div class="m">
          <a class="btn" id="download" href="#">
            <i class="fas fa-download">Download Resume</i>
          </a>
        </div>
        <div class="middle">
          <a class="btn" id="b" href="#">
            <i class="fab fa-facebook-f"></i>
          </a>
          <a class="btn" id="c" href="#">
            <i class="fab fa-twitter"></i>
          </a>
          <a class="btn" id="d" href="#">
            <i class="fab fa-linkedin-in"></i>
          </a>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</body>

</html>
```

I removed the particle code since it's irrelevant to the question.